# Unit testing: TEST Fixture, or TEXT Fixture

Tags: unit-testing

I'm reading a book [Microsoft .NET: Architecting Applications for the Enterprise](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/073562609X) by Dino Esposito.

In chapter 3 it talks about Unit testing and says "You start by grouping related tests in a *text fixture*. Text fixtures are just test-specific classes where methods typically represent tests to run."

It mentions text fixtures over and over again, so it can't be a typo.

Does the book mean "test fixtures"? Or are these two separate things?

Comment: By the way, after 4 paragraphs of "text fixture", they suddenly start saying "test fixture". Confusing at best!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's definitely an error we made in the book, and three people couldn't catch it!

Comment: Thanks Dino. I absolutely love the book and it is really helping me a lot. I have a lot of respect for you and the book, so any time I see something that I'm not sure about I have to find out! Thanks for taking the time to come on here and set the record straight!  :-)

Comment: By the way my guess is that it is the fault of spell-checker or a non-technical editor changing it from test fixture to text fixture!

Answer (score 2):

I would say it can't be anything else but a typo and should read "test fixture".

I'm sure this [Good C# Unit testing book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509445/good-c-unit-testing-book) SO question will get you a good book to read.

Comment: I would think so too but it goes on for several paragraphs. My only guess is that the tranlation from Italian didn't pick this up and the editors didn't either (since they probably were not technical).

Comment: That the curse of translations... being community translations done by people with poor english skills for people with even poorer skills :( or translations done by natives but who don't know anything whatsoever about the subject :(

Answer (score 1):

[**Test** fixture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_fixture) is the only one that I ever heard of.
"Test fixture" must be a typo.

Answer (score 1):

It is a typo. I am always catching myself writing Text when I mean Test. I guess Dino has the same affliction.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a typo, then it is a weird case of collective mistyping/auto complete errors ever. [Google](http://www.google.com/?q=text%20fixture) comes back with loads of hits. It's certainly referring to the same thing though so either way i think that answers the same question. I would say "text fixture" is incorrect though even if it used deliberately.

Comment: I think the mistranslation idea seems most likely